# Random connection problems

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1

**Problem**

My computer fails to open some websites randomly. I recently updated to Windows 8.1 and had everything working for 3-4 weeks. From then I started getting bluescreens but fixed it by updating my network driver. Now I'm getting random connection failures to different websites. I'm the only one from 5 in the network with this problem.

[**Ping Log**](http://pastebin.com/Suy96iwq)
[**IPConfig**](http://pastebin.com/FR29u8PE)

**Answer**

The problem was another access point in range with the same `SSID` than a saved one. To remove it open a command prompt(admin rights needed) and type `netsh wlan show profiles` and copy the name of the network that is causing the problem. After that enter `netsh wlan delete profile name="ProfileName"` and its done.

If you don't want to remove the network you have to get it higher in the "Connection list", so Windows stops trying to connect to the other network. To do this, open the wlan list, disconnect from the current access point click it again, hit the "Connect automatically" button and connect. After this the network should stop changing and you're happy again!
**Thanks for helping!**

Comment: Sounds like you network adapter is dying.  Have you tried a new/different one?  What was the Bluescreen Stop error and code you got?  Anything in the Event logs related to the networking when it drops?  Are you using the same DNS servers as the other computers?

Comment: I will try my RaspPI Adapter when it arrives. Bluescreen message was `irql not less or equal`. Im using the Google DNS, just like everyone else. I have some entries like `Timeout for the name xyz happened because no of the configured DNS servers responsed`. The driver update updated from version 3.x.x to 10.x.x thought, so I think the crash was really because of some bugs in the driver.

Comment: Btw the error code in chrome is `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` and says `The connection to xyz.com was reset due a network change.` So it seems like my computer is changing networks in behind?

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS server configuration. It sounds as if your current configuration is making it change networks and is timing out on you. Remember, your DNS must be the same as the router (many times the router may also use 255.255.0.0!) unless it is a server using a custom DNS or something like Google DNS

Also, take another look at your default gateway. Is it possible that it is set to a wrong ip?

Comment: The settings are ok, as shown here: [IPConfig](http://pastebin.com/FR29u8PE) but I disconvered, that another wireless network in my range uses the same SSID than the SSID of a friend of me, so I think it tries to connect to this access point. How can I prevent changeing access points? Mine is much stronger thought.

Comment: Makes sense. Try changing the SSID of your router. Type the ip for router (mine's at&t; 192.168.1.254) and enter in the access number (it is usually default under the router [there is a sticker with info] and  finding something saying settings or something of the nature) Also, if you do not wish to change the SSID, you can configure your wifi settings manually (setting your own 'SSID' as the external ip of your router) usually with advanced settings.